# Can't get this custom logging adapter example to work

Tags: python, logging

I have been looking at examples related to context logging here:
[Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information)

However, I cannot get the following example to work. The example should be demonstrating the use of custom adapters and goes on as the following:

```
# Here is a simple example:

class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
"""
This example adapter expects the passed in dict-like object to have a
'connid' key, whose value in brackets is prepended to the log message.
"""
def process(self, msg, kwargs):
    return '[%s] %s' % (self.extra['connid'], msg), kwargs

# which you can use like this:

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'connid': some_conn_id})

# Then any events that you log to the adapter will have the value of some_conn_id prepended to the log messages.
```

However, no matter what I have tried, I always get a key error:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

syslog = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s <<<CONTEXT: %(my_context)s>>> : %(message)s')
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)

adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'my_context': '1956'})

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(syslog)

logger.info('The sky is so blue', {'my_context': '6642'})


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/me/apps/Darwin64/python2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
msg = self.format(record)
File "/Users/me/apps/Darwin64/python2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
return fmt.format(record)
File "/Users/me/apps/Darwin64/python2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'my_context'
Logged from file myApp.py, line 62
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

--- Solution: EDIT_01 ---

I have changed the code so that it uses `adapter.info('The sky is so blue', {'my_context': '6642'})`. And it worked. However, I had to remove the `my_context` from the formatter. However, with the code below, the `my_context` bit is hardcoded and no matter what I pass in through the logger, it would always display the initial value. Is there a way to pass in some values to the adapter?

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
syslog = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(syslog)
adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'my_context': '1956'})
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
adapter.info('The sky is so blue', {'my_context': '6642'})
```

This would always generate:

```
2016-09-13 11:33:18,404 [1956] The sky is so blue
```

even we are passing `6642` through the logger.

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error with edit_01. the my_context keyword parameter should be passed _as keywords_ not as a dictionary of keys/values. Try adapter.info('The sky is so blue', my_context=6642)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the adapter for logging, not the logger. Try this:

```
import logging

class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        # use my_context from kwargs or the default given on instantiation
        my_context = kwargs.pop('my_context', self.extra['my_context'])
        return '[%s] %s' % (my_context, msg), kwargs

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
syslog = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(syslog)
adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'my_context': '1956'})
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

adapter.info('The sky is so blue', my_context='6642')
adapter.info('The sky is so blue')
```

Output:

```
2016-09-13 14:49:28,539 [6642] The sky is so blue
2016-09-13 14:49:28,540 [1956] The sky is so blue
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I am still not able to fully understand the concept of adapters. However, there is still an issue: that `my_context` value is hard-coded now. Please see `EDIT_01`.

Comment: Two things: you have to pass `my_context` as a keyword argument instead of passing it in a dict. Have a look at the source of the logging module. You haven't posted your actual CustomAdapter implementation

Comment: Thanks. This is a good solution to my question. All these concepts of `Adapters` and `Filters` are so abstract, I keep reading the docs and I keep having hard time understanding them. Your `CustomAdapter` is different in a way that I have not seen in any tutorial, once again thanks. Is it ok to assume that `Adapters` deal with the **information** side of the logging (messages, context etc.)? Does that open up an opportunity for passing all kind of information, even complex data such as stack-trace, together with the log messages?

Comment: I agree, the official documentation on logging is really sparse. Your understanding of Adapters is correct, you can do anything you want in the `process` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that will add hostname in the extra field.  Demonstrates how to open a socket to send logs to a server listening on port 9020. In this case, both the server and client are running on the same machine(localhost).  The server code is documented on the Logging Cookbook by Vinay Sajip:

```
import logging, logging.handlers
import socket

class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    """
    This example adapter expects the passed in dict-like object to have a
    'connid' key, whose value in brackets is prepended to the log message.
    """
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return '[%s] %s' % (self.extra['hostname'], msg), kwargs


def main():
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost',
                        logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.addHandler(socketHandler)

    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    my_hostname = socket.gethostname()

    my_custom_logger_adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'hostname': my_hostname})
    my_custom_logger_adapter.info('The here is to custom error log')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is what showed-up on the log server:

```
2022-03-18 11:41:56,391 - __main__ - INFO - [ultimo.local] The here is to custom error log
```

What you see on the log server, depends on how you have the formatter configured.